# Debian wheezy updates broke tr command

Tags: debian, glibc, coreutils, tr

After I updated the following packages yesterday in `debian wheezy`, `tr` command stop working.

```
Start-Date: 2016-02-16  23:10:06
Commandline: apt-get dist-upgrade
Upgrade: libkrb5-3:amd64 (1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u6, 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u7),
libk5crypto3:amd64 (1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u6, 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u7),
libgraphite2-2.0.0:amd64 (1.1.3-1, 1.3.5-1~deb7u1),
libc-bin:amd64 (2.13-38+deb7u8, 2.13-38+deb7u10),
libc6-i386:amd64 (2.13-38+deb7u8, 2.13-38+deb7u10),
libgssrpc4:amd64 (1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u6, 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u7),
iceweasel-l10n-de:amd64 (38.6.0esr-1~deb7u1, 38.6.1esr-1~deb7u1),
locales:amd64 (2.13-38+deb7u8, 2.13-38+deb7u10),
iceweasel:amd64 (38.6.0esr-1~deb7u1, 38.6.1esr-1~deb7u1),
libkrb5support0:amd64 (1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u6, 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u7),
multiarch-support:amd64 (2.13-38+deb7u8, 2.13-38+deb7u10),
libgcrypt11:amd64 (1.5.0-5+deb7u3, 1.5.0-5+deb7u4),
libkadm5clnt-mit8:amd64 (1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u6, 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u7),
libkadm5srv-mit8:amd64 (1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u6, 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u7),
libc6-dev:amd64 (2.13-38+deb7u8, 2.13-38+deb7u10),
krb5-locales:amd64 (1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u6, 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u7),
libkdb5-6:amd64 (1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u6, 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u7),
libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 (1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u6, 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u7),
libc-dev-bin:amd64 (2.13-38+deb7u8, 2.13-38+deb7u10),
libc6:amd64 (2.13-38+deb7u8, 2.13-38+deb7u10),
libc6-dev-i386:amd64 (2.13-38+deb7u8, 2.13-38+deb7u10)
End-Date: 2016-02-16  23:10:28
```

## Output example

```
> echo abcdefgh | tr -d [:alnum:]
bcdefgh

> echo abcdefgh | tr -Cd [:alnum:]
a

> type tr
tr is /usr/bin/tr
```

Comment: Is it possible that tr is somehow an alias or function? What does `type tr` output?

Comment: @Starfish ↑ `tr` is `/usr/bin/tr`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have a file named `a`?

```
$ echo [:alnum:]

$ touch a
$ echo [:alnum:]
a
```

Quote your strings.

```
$ echo '[:alnum:]' | tr -d '[:alnum:]'
[::]
```